# How to use -XX:-UseSplitVerifier in cmd line

Tags: java, code-coverage

Can anybody tell me how to use -XX:-UseSplitVerifier in command line. I get the error

```
C:\Users\emahaboo\Desktop>java -jar testJar1.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at
branch target 11
Exception Details:
  Location:
    testClass1.<init>()V @4: ifnonnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b200 4159 c700 0757 b800 4b03 324c 2ab7
    0000010: 0001 2b03 0454 b1

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put it before `-jar` ?

```
java -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -jar testJar1.jar
```